# Pass-through authentication not working on domain member server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, authentication

The pass through authentication doesn't work on any member server (let's name it FS) in my domain. I have set up the exactly same username and password on a non-domain computer to access the shares. It works on a domain controller and also when I create a local user on FS. I can see in the logs that FS sends NTLM traffic to the DC when receiving the access request but the authentication fails. Does anyone have any clue of how to get it working? The users are insanely addicted to it and I don't want to promote the member servers to domain controllers.
(The OS on the servers is Windows Server 2012 R2, the client it Win 10)

EDIT: A bit deeper investigation involving the netlogon service debug logging showed up that the requests are not relayed to DC from FS. Is there any possibility of forcing all the requests to be sent to the domain/server?

Comment: Why don't you join clients to your domain?

Comment: The users are used to access their shares from their personal devices where they set up identical username and password. They are used to if for a long time and we were just implementing a new server infrastructure.

Comment: Why bother with domain at all then? Just create a batch file that creates users and run it on every server. You can also use credential manager.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; for passthru authentication to work the way you want it to the computers need to be joined to the domain. An alternative solution is to write a batch file that logs into the server and maps a drive on the non domain joined computer to FS.

You have not addressed the fact that the local computer name makes up the "domain" component in the username.

If every person has a username on their computer "Bob" you seem to assume that the server attached to the domain "company.local" with the username "Bob" should allow passthru authentication from the client but the full usernames are actually different.

If the non domain joined computer named "personalmachine" tries to access FS the username sent to the server is bob@personalmachine.

If the username was bob@company.local they would be able to authenticate to the server but for that to happen their computer would need to be joined to the company.local domain.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it and that is basically what I wanted to do. I just realized that it really works the way netlogon has to:
"If the domain name specified is not trusted by the domain, the authentication request is processed on the computer being connected to as if the domain name specified were that domain name. NetLogon does not differentiate between a nonexistent domain, an untrusted domain, and an incorrectly typed domain name." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/102716 And that explains why it works on the DC and doesn't elsewhere. The question is if it's possible to alter it.

Comment: No I don't believe there is a direct way to change that behavior. If the computer is not joined to a domain and you do not specify the domain name by using the FQDN to identify the domain name them the local computer name will be assumed to be the domain name. The correct solution is to join the computers to the domain.